# Linked list sort from smallest to biggest

Tags: c, pointers, linked-list

I am trying sort a number in a linked list from small to big.

But its not working !

the debugger says there are a problem when i put the second number into the 
list ( in main )but i dont know why  .

Any help ?

```
#include<stdio.h>

#include<stdlib.h>

typedef struct list list;

struct list{

    int a;

    list *nxt;
};

void sort(list *l){

    int temp,tp;
    list *AIDE,*k;
    k=AIDE=(list*)malloc(sizeof(list));
    while (l->nxt!= NULL)
    {

        while (l->nxt->a < l->a)
        {

            temp=l->a;
            l=l->nxt;
            l->nxt->a=temp;
            l=l->nxt;
            while (l->a < AIDE->nxt->a )
            {
                tp=AIDE->a;
                AIDE->a=l->a;
                AIDE->nxt->a=tp;
                AIDE=AIDE->nxt;

            }
        }
        l=l->nxt;
    }
    while (k->nxt!= NULL)
    {
        l->a=k->a;
        l=l->nxt;
        k=k->nxt;
    }
    l->nxt=NULL;
}

int main() {

    list *t,*s;
    int n,i,c=0;
    printf("\n how many number you need to enter? ");
    scanf("%d",&n);
    s=t=(list*)malloc(sizeof(list)*n);
        while (c!=n)
        {
            printf("\n Donner le nb %d :",c+1);
            scanf("%d",&t->a);
            t=t->nxt;
            c++;
        }
        t->nxt=NULL;
        sort(s);
        while (t->nxt!=NULL)
        {
            printf("%d",t->a);
        }
    return 0;

}
```

Comment: Have you tried stepping through the code, line by line, in a debugger?

Comment: yeah the problem is here : 
 while (c!=n)
        {
            printf("\n Donner le nb %d :",c+1);
            scanf("%d",&t->a);
            t=t->nxt;
            c++;
        }
when i put the second number the program crush and stop working

Comment: What error do you get?

Answer (score 0):

In the loop where you have the problem, what do you think the expression `t=t->nxt` would do?

When you enter the loop, `t` is pointing to allocated but ***uninitialized*** memory, therefore dereferencing e.g. `t->nxt` will lead to [*undefined behavior*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).

A simple solution would be to e.g. do

```
t->nxt = t++ + 1;
```

Comment: I just want to go to the next struct in the linked list where the variable a is there..

Comment: @cip But when you allocate the memory there *is no* linked list, just an area of memory containing seemingly random data. Look at the memory as an array of` `n` number of `list` structures, each structure uninitialized.